# Как присвоить куки аккордеону?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется скрипт для многоуровневого меню. Нашёл команды конкретно для js в Magento.

```
Mage.Cookies.set('name', 'value'); // установить cookie с именем name и значением value
Mage.Cookies.get('name'); // получитьcookie с именем name
Mage.Cookies.clear('name'); // удалить cookie с именем name

    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var arrow = $('.multi-accordion li > a').next();
            if (arrow.length) {
            $(arrow).parent().append('<img src="v.svg" alt="">');
            }
    $('.multi-accordion li > a').on('click', function (event) {
        var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();
            Mage.Cookies.set('name', 'value');
            if ($next.length) {
            $next.slideToggle().parent().toggleClass('opened').siblings().children('ul').filter(':visible').slideToggle();
            event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

html разметка.

```
<div>
<ul class="multi-accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a.html">Category level 1 (a)</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a.html">Category level 2 (a)</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3a.html">Category level 3 (a)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3b.html">Category level 3 (b)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3c.html">Category level 3 (c)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2b.html">Category level 2 (b)</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2c.html">Category level 2 (c)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1b.html">Category level 1 (b)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1c.html">Category level 1 (c)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: откуда у вас взялся `$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active")`?

Comment: Прошу прощения, случайно скопировал не конечный вариант пробы, поправил.

Comment: но строка с `$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active")` так и осталась

Comment: а как второй уровень может быть открыт без первого?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33742/discussion-between-grundy-and-sergey-eremin).

Comment: Лучше на примере [ссылка](http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1b.html) Если нажать на `Category level 1 (a)` далее `Category level 2 (a)` будут открыты все уровни. Если снова нажать на `Category level 1 (a)` сначала закрыть, потом на неё же второй раз и снова все уровни открыты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю стоит немного изменить яваскрипт и разметку. А именно - добавить классы которые бы показывали, что у текущий узел можно развернуть. А так же вынести в CSS основные анимации.

Таким образом получим структуру аналогичную следующей

```
<ul>
    <li class="collapse"><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a.html">Category level 2 (a)</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3a.html">Category level 3 (a)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2b.html">Category level 2 (b)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Далее, добавляем обработчик клика только для тех `<a>`, которые лежат непосредственно в `<li>` с классом `collapse`, остальные остаются отдельными ссылками.

```
$('.multi-accordion .collapse > a').click(function(e) {
    var li = $(this).parent();//получаем сам li
    //ищем все элементы на этом уровне и ниже с классом expand, который показывает, что элемент раскрыт
    li.parent('ul').find('.expand')
      //добавляем текущий элемент если он до этого был схлопнут
      .add(li)
      //меняем состояние классов collapse и expand у выбранных элементов
      .toggleClass('collapse expand');

    // запрещаем поведение по умолчанию, конкретно здесь - переход по ссылке.
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Пример:

```js
$('.multi-accordion .collapse > a').click(function(e) {
 var li = $(this).parent();
    li.parent('ul').find('.expand').add(li).toggleClass('collapse expand');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
ul.multi-accordion,
.multi-accordion ul {
    list-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.multi-accordion ul {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.multi-accordion .expand > ul {
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="multi-accordion">
    <li class="collapse"><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a.html">Category level 1 (a)</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="collapse"><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a.html">Category level 2 (a)</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3a.html">Category level 3 (a)</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3b.html">Category level 3 (b)</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a/category-level3c.html">Category level 3 (c)</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2b.html">Category level 2 (b)</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2c.html">Category level 2 (c)</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1b.html">Category level 1 (b)</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1c.html">Category level 1 (c)</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Остался вопрос об элементе открытом по умолчанию.
Для этого нужно узнать какой именно элемент должен быть открыт. Так как элементы в данном случае соответствуют конкретным адресам, то поиск нужного элемента можно осуществить с помощью следующего селектора

```
jQuery('.multi-accordion a[href="'+location+'"]');
```

таким образом единственное что останется сделать - открыть все узлы на верхних уровнях

```
jQuery('.multi-accordion a[href="'+location+'"]').parents('li.collapse').toggleClass('collapse expand')
```

Пример на [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/25k71f4v/), в нем поиск по адресу заменен на поиск по id.

Comment: "Я думаю стоит немного изменить яваскрипт и разметку" - не-не-не! Он же нас опять замучает!!

Comment: @Qwertiy :-D уже в процессе, заходите в чат

Comment: В какой именно? Впрочем, мне что-то лень...

Comment: @Qwertiy, в этом вопросе [который](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33742/discussion-between-grundy-and-sergey-eremin)

Comment: Парни, да вас же никто не заставляет помогать. Мне интересно научиться делать меню аккордеон с нужным функционалом. Этот сервис для учащихся и желающих им помочь.

Comment: @SergeyEremin: Сергей, вы заблуждаетесь насчет предназначения Stack Overflow. Его цель — накопление базы решений, которые будут впоследствии полезны другим пользователям. Если кто-то помогает вам дебажить код по шагам, используя чат — это их личная инициатива. Сайт для такой помощи не предназначен.

Comment: Если почитать комментарии, то там всё сводится к тому "учите учебники и т.п." Вот поэтому больше русским сервисом не буду пользоваться. На зарубежном дают решение сразу, и в учебном плане оно полезно, сразу понятно, и с той точки зрения, что вы сказали.

Comment: @SergeyEremin, а тыкните в место где в ваших вопросах все свелось к  _"учите учебники и т.п."_ и почему вы игнорируете тот факт, что из двух вопросов которые вы задали конкретно по аккордеону, вам ответили на оба, и при этом на один из них дали множество вариантов решения?

Comment: А вы не читали всю переписку с Qwertiy, там часто встречалось "да выучи наконец это, выучи то. Голословно не говорю. А при том, что дал неверный ответ с синтаксической ошибкой, что в итоге понять не мог почему в учебниках так пишут, у него иначе. Поэтому его ответ не считайте. К решению пришёл по справочникам.

Comment: Последовал совету, разбил своё меню на три задачи, сам аккордеон, отдельно присвоение класса для оформления, и отдельно функция запоминания открытого меню. Решения то в итоге нет. Спасибо вам за помощь!!! Но ответ не подходит, для него нужно php код менять, пробовал, не выходит. А в большинстве случаев видел, что путём js меняют только класс.

Comment: @SergeyEremin, если вы нашли решение сами, можете опубликовать его и отметить принятый ответ :-)

Comment: @SergeyEremin, _пробовал, не выходит._ ну так можно же задать конкретный вопрос по пхп и все :-) какой код есть, какую разметку надо получить и как вы пытались сами.

Comment: Его в код в вопросе вписал. Итог тот, что и это решение не способно привести к готовому решению. Просто вы меня хаяли, что это мне не нравится, что то... Но я понимал, что если сразу не продумать так, чтобы все функции срослись, то будут проблемы. А теперь потраченное время на кучу вариантов, которые не работают.

Comment: Задал по php индийцам, которые моментально дают готовый код, но с такой задачей тишина. Сам перепробовал добавлять условия для смены класса, не вышло.

Comment: @SergeyEremin :-D  ну вот, а говорили _заграница нам поможет_ :-D